# Spring REST Controller Saving JSON Post

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am stuck on something and after a day of searching and trying different things I am throwing in the towel. I have 2 basic domains, a blog post and an author. I have left a little code out to keep this post short.

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String body;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String teaser;

    private String slug;

    @CreatedDate 
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date postedOn;

    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;

    // getters & setters    
}

@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    // getters & setters 
}
```

The controller looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {

    private PostService postService;

    @Autowired
    public PostController(PostServiceImpl postService){
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public Iterable<Post> list(){
        return postService.list();
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public Post create(@RequestBody Post post){
        return postService.save(post);
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public Post read(@PathVariable(value="id") long id){
        return postService.getPost(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT )
    public String update(@PathVariable(value="id") int id){
        return "post.update()";
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE )
    public String delete(@PathVariable(value="id") int id){
        return "post.delete()";
    }


}
```

And all the service method does is take the Post POJO and call the save method on the repository. This is my question and I feel dumb for even asking it. When I post JSON from Postman with no author (null) everything works fine. I am just not sure how the heck to post a json object with a new author or an existing one.

This works

```
{
    "title" : "A new post created from JSON",
    "slug" : "a-new-post",
    "teaser" : "post teaser",
    "body" : "post body",
    "postedOn" : "2015-11-07"
}
```

When I try and post this JSON

```
{
    "title" : "A new post created from JSON",
    "slug" : "a-new-post",
    "teaser" : "post teaser",
    "body" : "post body",
    "postedOn" : "2015-11-07",
    "author" : {
        "firstName": "Joe",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "email": "jsmith@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
{
    "timestamp": 1447018768572,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException",
    "message": "org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.therealdanvega.domain.Post.author -> com.therealdanvega.domain.Author; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.therealdanvega.domain.Post.author -> com.therealdanvega.domain.Author",
    "path": "/posts/"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to persist the Author. From the Post point of view, the Author you are presenting to it is Transient as it has no id, thus mapping cannot be done between Post and Author.

So create a persistent object of the Author and then insert it into the Post entity.

Comment: So I updated my PostService save method to first call the authorService.save(post.author) and that seems to work out just fine. Thanks. Just curious what would i pass in the case where I already knew who the author was? Maybe and id? author: { "id" : 1 }

Comment: Well I would say to query the author by name or id and then attach it to the Post using your setters. A simple ID should also be enough but you might run in the same problem. So from the top of my mind it will be someting like `Post post = new Post();` `post.setAuthor(authorService.get(authorId));` // set the rest of the info into `post `//  `postService.save(post);`